# How do I use CMake with debugging information?

Tags: cmake, windows-10

At the moment I'm compiling via

```
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
```

I'm not sure if this makes sense but it works. I would like to use the debugging of CMake which, afaik, can be set via `DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`. When I try to use this the compiling itself works:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
```

but here I don't get an .exe file somewhere. I guess I miss the `--build` or `--config` option from before but how do I properly add them?

edit: Thanks to vre's input I'm coming along better. However, this is the output now:

```
C:\geant4\sim> cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE


-- Build files have been written to: C:/geant4/sim
```

why is the build type not used?

Comment: Working with CMake is a two step process. First you configure your project by running `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .` Then you build your project by running `cmake --build . --config Debug`

Comment: @vre Thanks a lot! The prefix "Debug" at the end of the build command, is it only the folder name?

Comment: No, that's the configuration to build. Out of the box CMake is aware of `Debug,Release,RelWithDebInfo` configurations (or call them build types). You may explicitely specify the build and source folders by using the `-B` and `-S` options, e.g. `cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

Comment: @vre Thanks again! When I use the above commands, I receive above output. Is this correct resp. does it make sense? Shouldn't the build type be considered?

Comment: It depends. When you use a single config generator it is definitely considered. But as you specified `Windows-10` tag you are probably using Visual Studio or MSVC. That is a  multi config generator and you need to specify the --config when building from command line. See CMake online [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) for the command line options.

Comment: I always prefer explicitly setting the CMake generator, I suppose in your case this would be either "Visual Studio 16 2019" or "Visual Studio 17 2022" So the CMake command line would take another arg `-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"`. To specify the build architecture you would use another arg `-A`. For 32bit it is `-A Win32` and for 64bit it is `-A x64`.

Comment: @vre Thanks for your help! Tbh, I'm a bit overwhelmed. Could you please provide me the entire syntax? Despite from that, I found " --config <cfg>
    For multi-configuration tools, choose configuration <cfg>.
 " but when I use " cmake --build . --config cfg " I receive " This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of cfg|x64 "

Comment: For " cmake --build . --config -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" " I receive " CMake Error: Invalid value used with --config "

Comment: OK. The configuration call should be `cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64` for the 64 bit build. The build call should be `cmake --build <builddir> --config Debug`. MAke sure you delete the file `CMakeCache.txt` in the build folder when reconfiguring. I just noticed my `building from command line` phrase could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! This works now. Is it possible to combine all these commands in a single terminal syntax? However, I am stuck the next point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872030/abort-has-been-called

Comment: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only relevant for single configuration generators. The Visual Studio generators are all multi configuration generators requiring you to pass `--config <Configuration Name>` every time you use `cmake` with the build directories for things **other than (re)configuration**.

Comment: @fabian thanks for the input, I'll try to get a hold of it :)